# Change Graphql json response Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql-ruby

This is simple query:

```
query {
   comment(id: 1) {
      id,
      title
   }
}
```

And it result look like this:

```
{
   "data": {
      "comment": {
         "id": 1,
         "title": "Hello world"
      }
   }
}
```

Now, i want change json result to:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "title": "Hello world"
}
```

I'm using rails and gem graphql-ruby. Somebody can help me!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right

```
irb(main):007:0> hash = {"data": {"comment": {"id": 1, "title": "Hello World"}}}
=> {:data=>{:comment=>{:id=>1, :title=>"Hello World"}}}
irb(main):008:0> result = hash[:data][:comment]
=> {:id=>1, :title=>"Hello World"}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the graphql-ruby gem, you should be able to just add .as_json to the end of the query after retrieving the desired data:

```
results = client.query(hello_world_query).data.comment.as_json
```